# Can i call setContentView() method in getView() method of Android?

Tags: android

Can I call `setContentView()` method in a `getView()` method? If so, how?
Actually, I have a List that I am using to show some views like TextView, Imageview, and Button. Now on a button click event I want to show some other View. Here is my code:

```
Button select = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
select.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View arg0) {
     setContentView(R.layout.search);
  }
});
```

But it is giving me a syntax error because I am using this method in a BaseAdapter class.

Is there any other way to do this.?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try `YourCurrentActivity.this.setContentView(R.layout.search);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `getView(...)` and create `row` layout and put imageview,textview,Button

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) CurrentContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

        }  
   }
```

and see this http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Comment: R.layout.row is second l ayout for list row

Answer (score 1):

If you are extending base adapter class then you can pass your context in your extended adapter class. Then you can use that context to set your contents view.

context.setContentView(R.layout.search);

Another method is you can use broadcast receiver and send a broadcast from your adapter class to your activity class and their you can update your activity.

I havn't tried first method but i have tried second method to change the views in acitvity.

Comment: I tried your first method n its working correctly. thanks for the solution.

Comment: You should mark as answer whenever you find any answer because others should not waste their time to solve your problem... and welcome